# SEO urls to Dynamic downgrade

Tags: url, dynamic, seo, phpbb

I am using phpbb forum, with some seo plugin, which turned all my dynamic urls `"viewtopic.php?=1234"` to SEO urls such as `"/super-jackpot-t821.html"`. I was happy with it.

but now problme is, i have moved host, moved phpbb to sub folder and upgraded to latest phpbb. Now that plugin stopped working and all the urls are already indexed by google, yahoo etc.

So i was thinking is it possible to 301 redirect SEO urls back to normal urls? May be picking the last `821` number of seo url using HTACCESS and turning it back to `viewtopic.php?t=821` ???

thankx.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a htaccess guide i found.

http://www.garnetchaney.com/htaccess_tips_and_tricks.shtml

to match 0 to 9999 the regex should be ^[0-9]{1,4}$

Comment: Thank you but i am looking for little specific answer, since i am new to rewrite thing. I found a solution but it's still not close i think.`RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\.html$ viewtopic.php?t=1 [QSA,L]`